# Is there something like Perl's Catalyst routing for node.js?

Tags: node.js, perl, routes, catalyst, dispatch

Perl's Catalyst framework has an [excellent URL dispatching/routing mechanism](http://www.catalyzed.org/2009/05/chained-the-awesomesauce.html) that allows chaining methods together to modularize routing.

Through rigorous application of the Scientific Method, I have determined that is 1942.49 times better than rails-style routing for my current projects.  I'm currently writing something using node.js.

Is there a framework for node that uses catalyst-style dispatching (especially "chaining")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using express  you could potentially use middleware http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware and connect to simulate simular solution. https://github.com/senchalabs/connect

I hope this helps a bit with this question :).